# RESTful notification when resource change

Tags: rest, notifications

I have a RESTful web service and a rich client application using it.
I need to implement multiple user working concurrently with this service so that when someone change something it will be reflected, as soon as possible not in a transacted maner, on the other users clients.

I've though of using Web Socket to notify the other clients.

1) Is that good?
2) Are there any other options that not involve long polling?

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't worked much on REST or JSON but to avoid polling, I guess you could implement a subscribe/notify mechanism.
The user clients will expose an endpoint "listening" for events i.e. a small web service deployed on the client side.
User client on start up registers for notification sending the port (or even full URL) it expects the notification of changes.
When a change is done, a dispatcher running in the web service can send the notification via an event (encapsulating information regarding the change) to all registered clients.

Comment: This solution may be good inside local network but it will not work on the internet. Most companies do not allow for outside machine to talk to an inside machine.
I hoped someone already play with WebSocket which will work even on the internet because the client is the one initiating the call.

Comment: But your web service is already exposed to the public network right?Since external clients can access the web service.Why do you suppose an outbound connection from the web service (acting as a client) to the client (acting as a server will) be cut off?Unless I am misunderstanding the topology you have in mind

Comment: Because when the client accessing the service their firewall see it as outbound connection, which is usually allowed. When the server (act as client) try to connect the client (act as server) the client's firewall see it as inbound connection which is usually not allowed.

Comment: You should not have a problem since remember we are taking about http connection.Usually firewalls are configured to allow http traffic and a port to allow the http event send to the client could be acceptable, e.g. use port 8080 if posible

Comment: What do you do in the case that the client is really just a browser?  For example, I write a website that is populated from data I supply from my web service.  Client 2 posts to that service and I want client 1 to be notified of those changes.  How do I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on use WebSocket to notify clients about changing resources.
I try it, see how it will work.

Comment: I've done it this way. Works beautifully. Why reinvent the wheel with client also being a server, websockets are designed just for this?